# How can I get the Moto Z USB Drivers?

Tags: usb-drivers, motorola

I want to use my Moto Z as a physical device, however I can't without the drivers.

The only thing I found was the Motorola Device Manager. However, plugging it in to my PC I get this, even though I have an internet connection on both my phone and laptop.

[image]

Is there any direct driver? Or, how can I fix it?

Comment: Direct driver for what? Mass Storage device? That isn't possible anymore... I don't know what that window is from/for though. The device should be recognized as a MTP (Media Storage Protocol) device, but you will have to toggle it on on each connection of the USB cable from the notification pull-down.

Comment: @acejavelin I really want to develop android applications with it.

Comment: https://www.skyneel.com/download-latest-motorola-usb-driver-with-installation-guide (Untested, that's why it's a comment and not an answer). But if you are going to do development, why not use Linux? No drivers are required for Android device and most distro's official repositories have fastboot/adb already available.

Comment: @acejavelin I'm not going to get a completely different OS just for development

Comment: @acejavelin the program I download gives an error "That account already exists"

Comment: Hmm... guess I have never seen that. What is giving you the error and where, in the MDM software of the Moto Z Drivers link I posted earlier? I was able to download it successfully, but do not have Windows to test with.

Comment: When I run the program downloaded from skyneel